# Conflict FB debug tells me og:image isn't defined

Tags: facebook, image

I have a xenforo forum that allows users to like or share pages to Facebook. I am having a problem getting og:image to be consistent. I have defined og:image yet there seems to be an inconsistency.
I am using the Facebook developer debug tool to scrape information from my site. The debugger shows the warning:"og:image could not be downloaded or is too small"

However, just a few lines below in the section titled: "Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties" and it displays my og:image that is on my site.

Yet, when a user actually performs an organic share, no image is shared on Facebook. What should I fix? Thank you

Comment: can you show your code/meta tags? What size is your image?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the picture is accessible and you are using the correct size:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.
>
> ...
>
> Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images